# Get a sequence number from 0 and alternate positive/negative incrementing every other time

Tags: math, lua

I would like to be able to obtain a (non-convergent) sequence of numbers by a simple calculation that would look like this: `0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4 ...`

By simple calculation I mean being able to do it with a single variable that would start from 1 (or 0) without having to rearrange this sequence.

I made several (unsuccessful) attempts in Lua, here is what it should look like in principle (this example only alternates 0s and 1s):

```
do
    local n = 0
    for i = 1, 10 do print(n)
        n = n==0 and 1 or -n + (n/n)
    end
end
```

Is this possible and how?

**Update:**

I just succeeded like this:

```
local n, j = 0, 2
for i = 1, 10 do print(n)
    n = n==0 and 1 or j%2==0 and -(n+(n/math.abs(n))) or -n
    j = j + 1
end
```

But I have to help myself with a second variable, I would have liked to know if with only `n` it would be possible to do it?

Comment: `n = (n > 0 and 0 or 1) - n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by @EgorSkriptunoff in comment of my question, his approach is:

```
n = (n > 0 and 0 or 1) - n
```

The output of:

```
local n = 0
for i=1,10 do io.write(n..", ")
    n = (n > 0 and 0 or 1) - n
end
```

Actually gives:
`0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5,`

Answer (score 1):

Simply "emit" both `n` and `-n` in each iteration:

```lua
for n = 0, 10 do
  print(n)
  print(-n)
end
```

Comment: It's a good solution, I could have, but I can't afford it too much in the configuration where I am unfortunately

Comment: Then you should mention that there are constraints, and, more importantly, name them.

Comment: 1. `n * -1` can be written as `-n`; 2. This will emit `0` twice.

Answer (score 1):

The whole numbers are enumerable. Thus there exists a mapping from the natural numbers to whole numbers. You'll now have to use a loop to loop over natural numbers, then compute a function that gives you a whole number:

```lua
-- 0, 1...10, -1...-10 -> 21 numbers total
for n = 1, 21 do
    local last_bit = n % 2
    local sign = 1 - (2 * last_bit)
    local abs = (n - last_bit) / 2
    print(sign * abs)
end
```

prints

```
-0
1
-1
2
-2
...
10
-10
```

on Lua 5.1; on newer Lua versions, you can use `n // 2` instead of `(n - last_bit) / 2` to (1) use ints and (2) make extracting the abs cheaper.

Comment: It's a very good approach so I validate it but @EgorSkriptunoff proposed a better one in comment of my question, unfortunately he didn't give a complete answer...